# PayloadTypeRouter directly sending into a Transformer without channel in between?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, messaging, enterprise-integration

I need to use a `PayloadTypeRouter` and want to send the routed message directly into a `Transformer`, `Filter` or `ServiceActivator`. All should be configured with Kotlin DSL (or Java DSL).

Currently, a nice looking part of code looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    fun routeAzureC2DMessage() = integrationFlow {
        channel(IoTHubChannelNames.IOTHUB_TO_DEVICE_CHANNEL)
        route<IotHubC2DRequestMessage<IotHubC2DRequest>> {
            when (it.payload) {
                is IotHubDesiredPropertyUpdate -> IoTHubChannelNames.DESIRED_PROPERTY_UPDATE
                is IotHubMessageToDevice -> IoTHubChannelNames.MESSAGE_TO_DEVICE
            }
        }
    }
```

and then continued by (one side of the routing)

```
    @Bean
    fun processMessageToDevice() = integrationFlow {
        channel(IoTHubChannelNames.MESSAGE_TO_DEVICE)
        filter(StructureFilter())
        transform(MessageTransformer())
        channel(SharedChannelNames.CLOUD2DEVICE)
    }
```

I would like to get rid of the unneeded channel `IoTHubChannelNames.MESSAGE_TO_DEVICE`. I tried several approaches and in another part of the project I figured out something like this (Java DSL)

```
IntegrationFlows
            .from(channelName)
            .route({ message: IotHubMessage -> message.javaClass }) { router: RouterSpec<Class<*>?, MethodInvokingRouter?> ->
                router
                    .subFlowMapping(DeviceToCloudMessage::class.java) {
                        it.handle(gateway, "handleD2CMessage")
                    }
                    .subFlowMapping(DeviceTwinUpdateMessage::class.java) {
                        it.handle(gateway, "handleDeviceTwinReportedProperty")
                    }
            }
            .get()
```

Are `subFlowMapping`s the only way to get rid of the channels in between? I would like a solution where I can still use `when (it.payload)` and then instead of the channel/channel name could return a new `integrationFlow` or some other form of Flow definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution at the moment is really via API:

```
inline fun <reified P, T> route(
        crossinline function: (P) -> T,
        crossinline configurer: KotlinRouterSpec<T, MethodInvokingRouter>.() -> Unit) {
```

What you are asking with that `when(...) is` syntax is out of support at the moment.

Feel free to raise a GH issue on the matter and share as much as possible details what is that from Kotlin perspective and how it could be used in Spring Integration DSL.

**UPDATE**

On the other hand it is not so bad with current Kotlin support:

```
            route<Int, Boolean>({ it % 2 == 0 }) {
                subFlowMapping(true) { handle<Int> { p, _ -> p * 2 } }
                subFlowMapping(false) { handle<Int> { p, _ -> p * 3 } }
            }
```

So, the argument of the `route()` method is a `when()` and `subFlowMapping()` is `is` with `->` output as an `integrationFlow` builder result. So, probably we won't pursue a Kotlin `when()` which won't give us too much gain unless we lose `subFlowMapping` in favor of `->` operator...

**UPDATE 2**

After more thinking about this and looking to a possible solution, I have to retract my request for this `when()`-kind feature request.

The main problem that `IntegrationFlow` together with all its configuration must be registered in the application context upfront, before usage. What you are asking with the `when()` in the original router function is not what the framework can detect and process for you. This function is not a part of the framework to take responsibility for the produced result.

Well, we could check for the `IntegrationFlow` return to make a decision how to call, but there is no guarantee that the flow you are going to return from that function is a registered bean. And when we really register it and try to use in such a function, it is not a difference with what we have so far with channels returning from that function and their mapping in some flow bean somewhere.

We can register `IntegrationFlow` as bean automatically in some designed for this instructions like `subFlowMapping()`. Anyway it is done only once, on configuration phase. But it is not so good to do that when end-user code returns flows at runtime. It is better to return channels or some other keys where we have a mapping for existing flows.

I personally prefer do not ignore a `MessageChannel` abstraction and use it when ever I need to distribute a logic between different flows. The code in a single flow looks more cleaner when it is linear and represents a single logic unit of work. The other flows might be reused in other logic though. What I would only need is to point to those flows input channels from other places!

Nevertheless my main point is: we must register and `IntegrationFlow` before we are going to send a message to it.

Comment: Thanks! An important feature (at least for me) of the kotlin `when()` is that it provides you 'compile time exhaustiveness checks'. That simply means: if I introduce a new subtype of message in my first example above, I would get a compile time error vs. the subflow implementation, where there will be an error only at runtime, logged into some `errorChannel`.
So I think it still might be beneficial to have that in the Kotlin DSL.

Comment: Not sure what you mean if we really curry the generic (compile time) type from the route function output to those subFlowMappings.

Comment: See an UPDATE 2. My big `-1` for your request.